# Trying to integrate Google AdMob in libgdx game on iOS results in "framework not found GoogleUtilities"

Tags: ios, libgdx, admob, robovm

I want to include google ads into my libgdx game. In android this is working straightforward. However in iOS there are some complications:

I updated the `Info.plist.xml` file with my ad-identifier.
Then I added the following entries to the robovm.xml file:

into the `<frameworks>` element:

```
<!--AdMob-->
<framework>GoogleAppMeasurement</framework>
<framework>GoogleMobileAds</framework>
<framework>GoogleUtilities</framework>
<framework>nanopb</framework>
```

before the `<frameworks>` element:

```
<frameworkPaths>
    <path>libs</path>
</frameworkPaths>
```

In the main `gradle.build` file I added an entry `allProjects.ext.robopodsVersion = "2.2.3"` and added into the iOS project section `implementation "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robopods-google-mobile-ads-ios:$robopodsVersion"` so this section looks like this:

```
project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robopods-google-mobile-ads-ios:$robopodsVersion"
        api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"

    }
}
```

Then I downloaded the `googlemobileadssdkios.zip` file and put its contents under `libs` folder in the iOS project. The contents under ios/libs look like this:

```
|- nanopb.xcframework
    |- Info.plist
    |- ios-armv7_arm64
        |- ...
    |- ios-i386_x86_64-simulator
        |- ...
    |- ios-x86_64-maccatalyst
        |- ...
|- PromisesObjC.xcframework
    |- Info.plist
    |- ios-armv7_arm64
        |- ...
    |- ios-i386_x86_64-simulator
        |- ...
    |- ios-x86_64-maccatalyst
        |- ...
|- Licenses
    |- ...
|- GoogleUtilities.xcframework
    |- Info.plist
    |- ios-armv7_arm64
        |- ...
    |- ios-i386_x86_64-simulator
        |- ...
    |- ios-x86_64-maccatalyst
        |- ...
|- GoogleMobileAds.framework
    |- GoogleMobileAds
        |- ...
    |- Headers
        |- ...
    |- Modules
        |- ...
|- GoogleAppMeasurement.framework
    |- GoogleAppMeasurement
        |- ...
    |- Modules
        |- ...
```

So summarised: under each .xcframework directory there are, besides this `Info.plist` file, the directories `os-armv7_arm64`, `ios-i386_x86_64-simulator` and `ios-x86_64-maccatalyst`.

When I try to run the app on the simulator from Android Studio (using the robovm android studio plugin `idea-2.3.10-SNAPSHOT.zip`) I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] 09:12:34.831 ld: framework not found GoogleUtilities
[ERROR] 09:12:34.832 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[ERROR] Couldn't compile app
```

I had the suspicion that this has something to do with the `xcframework` that are used by GoogeUtilities and was assured by the open issue https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/issues/468 which basically tells that there is currently no support for xcframworks, but linking to issue https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/pull/483 which is describing with little words that now a `variant` can be specified in the  element of the `<frameworkPaths>` element.

The question for me is now: how to proceed with the libs and how to define path variants so that it can run both in a iOS device and in the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me:

In the `robovm.xml` file replace the `<frameworkPaths>` element with the following part:

```
<frameworkPaths>
    <path variant="device">arm_libs</path>
    <path variant="simulator">sim_libs</path>
</frameworkPaths>
```

Note that (also in the `robovm.xml` file) in the `frameworks` section for me the following part had to be added:

```
<framework>PromisesObjC</framework>
```

Using the shell in ios subproject create two directories: `arm_libs` and `sim_libs`

Go into `arm_libs` directory and execute the following commands:

```
cp -r ../libs/GoogleUtilities.xcframework/ios-armv7_arm64/GoogleUtilities.framework .
cp -r ../libs/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework .    
cp -r ../libs/GoogleMobileAds.framework .     
cp -r ../libs/PromisesObjC.xcframework/ios-armv7_arm64/PromisesObjC.framework .
cp -r ../libs/nanopb.xcframework/ios-armv7_arm64/nanopb.framework .            
cp -r ../libs/Licenses .
```

Go into `sim_libs` directory and execute the following commands:

```
cp -r ../libs/GoogleUtilities.xcframework/ios-i386_x86_64-simulator/GoogleUtilities.framework .
cp -r ../libs/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework .                                                 
cp -r ../libs/GoogleMobileAds.framework .     
cp -r ../libs/Licenses .
cp -r ../libs/PromisesObjC.xcframework/ios-i386_x86_64-simulator/PromisesObjC.framework .
cp -r ../libs/nanopb.xcframework/ios-i386_x86_64-simulator/nanopb.framework .
```

This gives the following structure:

```
|- arm_libs
    |- GoogleAppMeasurement.framework
        |- ...
    |- GoogleMobileAds.framework
        |- ...
    |- GoogleUtilities.framework
        |- ...
    |- Licenses
        |- ...
    |- PromisesObjC.framework
        |- ...
    |- nanopb.framework
        |- ...
|- sim_libs
    |- GoogleAppMeasurement.framework
        |- ...
    |- GoogleMobileAds.framework
        |- ...
    |- GoogleUtilities.framework
        |- ...
    |- Licenses
        |- ...
    |- PromisesObjC.framework
        |- ...
    |- nanopb.framework
        |- ...
```

Now running in simulator and on iPhone works for me.